# How to create a periodic polling process?

Tags: vb.net, web-services, wcf

I'm looking for suggestions/guidance/examples on how to create a periodic polling process [an application] using the latest technique(s).

I have a web application that inserts an entry into a queue table based upon a Users action. The entry represents a request to do something. Once the entry is processed, it will be removed from the queue. Until processed, there can be more than 1 request in the queue.

I want to poll that queue table every 3 minutes, 24 by 7 and then initiate a 'process' to handle the request(s).

Should this periodic polling process [an application] be a console app, a WCF service or a regular web service?  Should I use a multi-threading technique to process multiple requests that may be in the queue at a given 'poll' time (every 3 minutes)?

I've seen a few examples of polling when I Google, but they seem old and out-dated. Some use threads, others tasks, timers, etc.

Somewhat confused as what is the best approach. Any "best practice" suggestions/guidance/examples would be most appreciated.

Comment: There are no "best practice", it all depends on the specific situation. Ex: For my site, I have pooling that are on a web page and some that are in a console app. Some have threading and some don't. You should ask yourself, what is the advantage of using a console app for my specific need, can my process be threaded, ...

Comment: the_lotus..can you share an example of a console app that you wrote that has threading? I believe i should multi-thread in order to process multiple requests in the queue table that I use. Note: I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a WCF service is primarily useful when you need to do remoting, in your case your polling is autonomous, so there is no need at all for anything other than a single thread. The simplest way to do what you want would be a a standard Windows service. In your service, start a thread in an infinite loop. Inside, put in your code to check the queue and process it, and then a 3 minutes pause (Thread.Sleep(180000)).

As far as multi-threading when processing the queue that is up to you, and will have no effect on the polling itself. Is the task to be run expected to take a long time? Would parallelism offer a distinct advantage? Depending if you expect to process thousands of requests or five every poll, or if the task to be run might take more than 3 minutes, your answers will be different.

Simplest example:

```
Private Const pollingRefreshMs = 180000

Private pollingThread As New Thread(AddressOf PollQueue) With {.IsBackground = True}

Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
    pollingThread.Start()
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
    ' Abort the polling thread when the service is stopped.
    pollingThread.Abort()
End Sub

Private Sub PollQueue()
    Dim bAborted As Boolean = False
    Do
        Try
            ' Check queue and process items here, possibly spawning a separate thread for each item...

            Thread.Sleep(pollingRefreshMs) ' Pause the polling for 3 minutes.
        Catch ex As ThreadAbortException
            bAborted = True
        End Try
    Loop Until bAborted
End Sub
```

Comment: I get this error ; Error 1 'Public Shared Sub Main()' has multiple definitions with identical signatures.

Comment: I think the error is quite self-explanatory. In any case the code above was a snippet, not a full working example with all the necessary parts.

Comment: Sorry, new to this..but I don't get how to resolve that error. There is a Service1.Designer.vb file with a Shared Sub Main()... hence the error. I get it you did not give a full working example. However, your example seems viable. I created a new project and selected window services. It created a service1.vb file. That's where I put the code....containing the Sub Main().

Comment: I edited the code above, it should work properly now.

Comment: OK...it compiled fine. I plan on testing and weighing the pros and cons of using the console app vs. the windows service. Thanks much!

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and mark as answered if it solved your problem!

Answer (score 0):

A very simple approach is to write a simple console application that polls your table and performs the necessary actions.  It should do this once and exit.  Launch the console application every three minutes from a task that is defined using the windows task scheduler.

Comment: I'd love it if the downvoter would provide some input as to why he/she downvoted my comment.  My suggested approach works extremely well for me in a similar situation.  It has an advantage over a long-running process: it avoids the inevitable management hassles  such as stopping it before a software release and starting it after a software release.  Windows Task scheduler is built-in to every version of windows and very simple to learn and use.

Comment: I created the console app and included code to spawn a separate thread for each request in the queue. It works. As suggested, I just need to launch it from a task in the windows task scheduler. Seems to do the job...thanks.

Comment: I think your approach is perfectly valid for internal single-use tools, but it is hard to deploy and manage in a commercial setting. Nevertheless I'll vote you up just so you at least finish even.