# wcf always live(with waiting)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

How to create WCF service which will work periodically?

```
--Start WCF Service

while(true)

{

-Start Method executes

-Start Method finishes

-Wait(milliseconds)

}
```

Is it right way or you know better way to do this?

Comment: This question needs some work.  You can host a WCF service in IIS or self host it, but you probably want to write a Windows service to do some periodic actions.  If you really need a Web application to stay alive, then you need to look at the Owin lifecycle.

Comment: Here's a very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27298379/how-to-create-a-periodic-polling-process/27304723#27304723